# Convert comma to space in list

Tags: python

how can we convert a string `[0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923]` to a form `[0.0034596999  0.0034775001  0.0010091923]` in python. I tried using `map`, `join` etc functions but I am unable to do so. Can anyone help?

Comment: That is a list of floats, not a string. And, what is a form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the string method `replace()` is an efficient solution; however thought I'd offer an alternate using `split()` and `join()`:

```
print ''.join(i for i in '[0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923]'.split(','))
>>> [0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]
```

Answer (score 1):

`"[0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923]".replace(",", "")` returns `"[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]"`

Have a look at the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) - there are many useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the string `replace()` method:

```
s = '[0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923]'
s = s.replace(',', '')
print(s)  # -> [0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string you could do as the other suggested. If it is a list of strings you could do:

```
new_list_without_comma = [x.replace(",", "") for x in list_with_comma]
```